# Detailed error message with web.config

Tags: error-handling, asp-classic

On hosting my website on goddady plesk server and when there an error with one of my pages it seems not to display in detail though i have a web.config file in my root folder. I don't know if maybe there's a problem with my web.config. the only tell it tells me is "There is a problem with the resource you are trying to access"

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What kind of pages : asp, aspx ? Which IIS version ?

Comment: Remember to include `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and make sure the file is saved as UTF-8 and this should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on Fasthosts (UK) shared hosting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It tends to give me the detailed errors that we need for Classic ASP development. Remember to turn that off when the site goes live.

Comment: what should i turn it off?

Comment: Once the site is live, you don't want users to see detailed errors. It could also lead to giving information away to bad people who might want to have a pop at the site. I tend to comment it out in case I need it later on for any debugging issues.